# Dynamically changing the max number of simultaneous connections?

Tags: mysql

Follow up question for question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478733/dynamically-change-the-number-of-db-connections-on-wordpress

I understand that I need to change the max_user_connections param, but can I do that dynamically? via code?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it per-user, with:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost'
   WITH
   MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
   MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
   MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
   MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

Changing it globally means to change the `max_user_connections` global system variable; it can be changed dynamically while the server is running by means of the `SET` statement.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html
you might create a procedure that sets the variables you're interested in and call that procedure from PHP or whatever language you use.